# object has no attribute 'slash_command'. Did you mean: 'add_command'

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Пытаюсь поставить Discord бота на хостинг Heroku, в итоге получаю подобную ошибку

```
AttributeError: 'rinokBbBot' object has no attribute 'slash_command'. Did you mean: 'add_command'?
```

Все мои `import` -

```py
# Discord
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ui import Button, View
from dislash import *
import asyncio
from asyncio import *

# Configs
import random
from time import *
import datetime
from datetime import *
import requests
```

файл `requirements.exe` -

```
requests
py-cord
db-sqlite3
asyncio
discord.py
dislash.py
DiscordUtils
discord-ext-forms
emoji==1.7
PyNaCl
discord-ui
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решил проблему**

Вся проблема была в конфликте **discord.utils** с **Py-Cord**

Решилось всё тем, что просто отказался от использования **Discord Utils**